# How can I make git pull work at startup on a raspberry pi using autostart ? (network connection needed)

Tags: raspbian, lxde, git, pi-3a+

I am working with a raspberry Pi, and what I need is to make it launch scripts at startup when internet connection is active.
I found a solution by setting instructions to be launched in the file below:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Here are all the instructions I tried to set in the autostart file :

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@ngrok http 888
@cd ~/Desktop/app
@git checkout master
@git pull origin master
@ruby /home/pi/Desktop/app/script1.rb some_argument
@python3 /home/pi/Desktop/app/script2.py
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

My issue is that ngrok instruction, and both python and ruby scripts are executed.
However, something is not working with the git pull, and therefore, both ruby and python scripts that should be updated with the git pull are not.

My other issue is I do not know how to test this properly other than just rebooting the raspberry, and looking at the results of my scripts to see if the most current version of the scripts was executed or not.

Anyone knows how I could correct this issue, or how I could test ? 
I tried "startx" but I get the error below:
`parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (permission denied)`

Any help ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Use a systemd boot service dependent on `network-online.service`: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autostart runs each command separately, not consecutively like a bash script.

In other words, `cd` will have no effect on subsequent commands. I suggest you stick all your commands in a bash script, and then have autostart run the script.

Comment: I did that and it works now, thanks !
Any insight on how to test autostart scripts other than just rebooting everytime ?

Comment: @Ouhbelle, do you mean, "how to run `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`" without rebooting? If so, IDK.

Comment: By the way, if my answer has helped you, feel free to [accept it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3287).

Comment: You could exit Xorg with Ctrl+Alt+F1, then in the console run `startx`. In that case the autostart script would be run without shutting completely down.